# Run jQuery AJAX function only after submit not on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a few jQuery / JavaScript functions that run AJAX queries, but shouldn't execute on the initial page load, only after the form has been submitted (it resubmits to itself with the form values as **get** parameters).

Here is the code for the two functions that seem to be executing automatically on the first load:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pageLink', function(){
    var pageNumber = $(this).attr('page');
    $.getJSON('/retrieve/'+pageNumber+location.search, function(data) 
    {
      build(data.results);
  });
```

and

```
$.getJSON('/retrieve/1'+location.search, function(data) 
    {
      build(data.results);
   });
```

**build** is just a helper function, I figure what's executing is one or both of these on page load, but not sure how to prevent that.

Is there a way to check for **GET** values in the URL and only execute the scripts if there are parameters there?  Or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `submit` trigger and `return false`.

```js
$("#form2").on("submit", function() {
  $.post("https://ipapi.co/json/", $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
    console.log("send it", "your city is " + json.city);
  }, "json");
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="form1">
  <input type="submit" value="normal" />
</form>

<br>

<form id="form2">
  <input name="text" type="text" value="blabla" />
  <input type="submit" value="with return false;" />
</form>
```

Comment: the page calls itself and needs to reload after the submit, will this work for that?  It seems like the 'submit' trigger will be lost when that happens?

Comment: You can use ajax to submit your form.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call the AJAX request on form submit using

```js
$('#form_id').on('submit', function() {
    console.log('form has been submitted...');
    // do any operation here
    return false; // remove this in real implementation
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_id">
  <button type="submit">Submit </button>
</form>
```